Resolve Script function in client script is not working in a suitelet
Here is the suitelet script to filter the sublist according to the value
`/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['N/search', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/email'],
    /**

 * @param{search} search
 * @param{serverWidget} serverWidget
 * @param{email} email
 */
    (search, serverWidget, email) => {
        /**
         * Defines the Suitelet script trigger point.
         * @param {Object} scriptContext
         * @param {ServerRequest} scriptContext.request - Incoming request
         * @param {ServerResponse} scriptContext.response - Suitelet response
         * @since 2015.2
         */

        const onRequest = (scriptContext) => {
            try {


                if (scriptContext.request.method === "GET") {

                    let form = serverWidget.createForm({
                        title: "Sending Onam Offers",
                    });
                    form.clientScriptFileId = 528;
                    let subsidiaryFilter = form.addField({
                        id: "custpage_subsidiary",
                        label: "Subsidiary",
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                        source: 'subsidiary'
                    });
                    let customerFilter = form.addField({
                        id: "custpage_customername",
                        label: "Customer",
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                        source: 'customer'
                    });
                    let subList = form.addSublist({
                        id: 'custpage_sublist',
                        label: 'Details',
                        type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST
                    });
                    subList.addField({
                        id: "custpage_customer",
                        label: "Customer Name",
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                    });

                    subList.addField({
                        id: "custpage_email",
                        label: "Customer Email",
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.EMAIL
                    });

                    subList.addField({
                        id: "custpage_totatlinvoiceamount",
                        label: "Total Invoice Amount",
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.CURRENCY
                    });
                    // subList.addField({
                    //     id: "custpage_subsidiary1",
                    //     label:"Subsidiary",
                    //     type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
                    // });
                    subList.addField({
                        id: "custpage_checkboxpromo",
                        label: "Send Promotion",
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX
                    });
                    form.addSubmitButton({
                        label: "Send Email"
                    });

                    let custName = scriptContext.request.parameters.customerName || '';
                    let subsidName = scriptContext.request.parameters.subsidiaryFilterId || '';
                    log.debug(subsidName);
                    subsidiaryFilter.defaultValue = subsidName;
                    customerFilter.defaultValue = custName;
                    let filter = [["trandate", "onorafter", "1/1/2024"], "AND", ['mainline', 'is', 'T'], "AND", ["amount", "greaterthan", "1000.00"]];
                    if (subsidName) {
                        filter.push("AND", ['subsidiary', 'anyof', subsidName]);
                    }
                    if (custName) {
                        filter.push("AND", ['entity', 'anyof', custName]);

                    }
                    log.debug(filter);
                    let invObj = search.create({
                        type: search.Type.INVOICE,
                        filters: filter,
                        columns: [
                            search.createColumn({
                                name: "entity",
                                summary: "GROUP",
                                label: "Name"
                            }),
                            search.createColumn({
                                name: "email",
                                join: "customer",
                                summary: "GROUP",
                                label: "Email"
                            }),
                            search.createColumn({
                                name: "amount",
                                summary: "SUM",
                                label: "Amount"
                            })
                        ]
                    });
                    let results = invObj.run().getRange({
                        start: 0,
                        end: 1000
                    });



                    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        subList.setSublistValue({
                            id: "custpage_customer",
                            line: i,
                            value: results[i].getText(invObj.columns[0])
                        });
                        subList.setSublistValue({
                            id: "custpage_email",
                            line: i,
                            value: results[i].getValue(invObj.columns[1])
                        });
                        subList.setSublistValue({
                            id: "custpage_totatlinvoiceamount",
                            line: i,
                            value: results[i].getValue(invObj.columns[2])
                        });


                    }
                    scriptContext.response.writePage(form);


                }







            } catch (e) {
                log.error("error", e.stack)
            }
        }

        return { onRequest }

    });
`

Here is the client script
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/url'],
/**
 * @param{url} url
 */
function(url) {
    
    /**
     * Function to be executed after page is initialized.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.mode - The mode in which the record is being accessed (create, copy, or edit)
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function pageInit(scriptContext) {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is changed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
     * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {
        try{
                
            let currObj = scriptContext.currentRecord;
            console.log("working...");
            if(scriptContext.fieldId=='custpage_subsidiary'){
              let subsidiaryFilter = scriptContext.currentRecord.getValue({
                   fieldId: 'custpage_subsidiary'
               });
               console.log("working...");
               console.log(subsidiaryFilter);
            }

        //     let customerId = currObj.getValue({fieldid:'custpage_customername'});
        // let subsid  = currObj.getValue({fieldid:'custpage_subsidiary'});
        if(scriptContext.fieldId ==='custpage_customername'|| scriptContext.fieldId ==='custpage_subsidiary'){
            let currenturl = url.resolveScript({
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_jj_sl_onam_off_otp7442',
                scriptId: 'customscript_jj_sl_onam_off_otp7442',
                returnExternalUrl: false,
                params: {
                    subsidiaryFilterId: subsidiaryFilter||'',
                    customerName: customerId||''
                }
            });



            console.log(currenturl);
            window.location.href = currenturl;
        };
            
        }catch(e){
            log.error("error",e.stack)
        }
    }

    // /**
    //  * Function to be executed when field is slaved.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function postSourcing(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Function to be executed after sublist is inserted, removed, or edited.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function sublistChanged(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Function to be executed after line is selected.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function lineInit(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Validation function to be executed when field is changed.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
    //  * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
    //  * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
    //  *
    //  * @returns {boolean} Return true if field is valid
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function validateField(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is committed.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  *
    //  * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function validateLine(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is inserted.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  *
    //  * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function validateInsert(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Validation function to be executed when record is deleted.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
    //  *
    //  * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function validateDelete(scriptContext) {

    // }

    // /**
    //  * Validation function to be executed when record is saved.
    //  *
    //  * @param {Object} scriptContext
    //  * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
    //  * @returns {boolean} Return true if record is valid
    //  *
    //  * @since 2015.2
    //  */
    // function saveRecord(scriptContext) {

    // }

    return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
    };
    
});

I did try getting the values from the  filter using client script I am getting a output as below image.The sublist is not changing according to the given filter.
The sublist should change according to the filter given

